# Need clarification of angular architecture for editor

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

#### Edited: Tried to simplify the posting

I need to create a simply github-flavored markdown "editor" with the following basic (typical) features

1. Preview panel that shows converted markdown text
2. An horizontal grippie that allows the textarea to be resized.
3. A toolbar with grouped buttons accessible via **click or hotkey**. As usual with editor toolbars, some buttons will perform immediate manipulation of the text (for example, *wrap or unwrap* selected text or insert/remove from beginning of the line) whereas in other instances, display a dialog to collect some data and **then** insert appropriate text.

For the last two weeks I have been trying to come up with an architecture (controller/service/directive) that properly covers these requirements.

Out of all the problems I am having, I think the issues boil down to three questions

1. What is needed? *Controller? Directive? Service? Combination? Multiple of each?*
2. What goes where? *Beyond the basic "the controller should not do DOM manipulation" or "the service is a singleton". For example, I am fairly certain that each toolbar button would be represented as a directive...but where would the functions that manipulate the textarea content go?*
3. What should be used to control all of this (i.e. the parent)? *Ultimately, is the markup on the page a Directive which in turn instantiates one or more controllers, services, and other directives?*

As I see it, the driving factors that are confusing me is that I will have multiple "editors" (i.e. textareas) on a page with each having their own toolbar, preview panel, and sizing grippie.

Yet, I **suspect** that the proper approach is to have the **bulk** of the functionality in an a single object (service?). For example, if the function is given *any* snippet of text, it should be able to wrap, unwrap, and determine status (i.e. should the toolbar button be displayed in an active/inactive state) of the selection of text in double asterisks for bolding purposes.

This implies that each textarea, along with corresponding toolbar buttons, be their own instances of something yet still have the ability to call into a single object (service?) passing in appropriate parameters for text content manipulation.

If I was writing this in C# or even plain javascript, I would have a parent class (say Editor) with supporting classes (maybe some of them as internals) (Say Toolbar, ToolbarButton, PreviewPanel, etc) and would create instances of each class *for each editor instance*.

*Maybe my problem is as simple as being unable to translate that design to the angular world...*

I would love some help/insight into any resources / code snippets / suggestions into what each feature should be presented as (directive / service / controller) and how all these sub-components can/should be instantiated by a single parent and how they can communicate with each other. I have read (or tried to read) the basic documentation and I have searched around, but almost all of what I find tends to be straight API reference material (angular docs) or fairly simplistic examples.

Thanks.

Comment: Way too long and way to broad. Need to scale this down to bite sized chucks and real code problems

Comment: That is what I was afraid of... part of my problem is that I am not really sure what to ask. Part of the problem is that it really is all related to the same question of "what is the correct way to architect this in angular" but there are multiple aspects of it that are tripping me up.. I will work on rewriting this later today. Thanks.

Comment: critical part is likely making sure all components are bound to one object in service so changes are inherited